# Get coodinates from point shapefile

Tags: qgis, convert, point, coordinates, line

I converted a line shapefile to points as you can see in the attached image. Is there a way to know the coordinates of each point?

I'm using QGIS 1.8.0

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Field Calculator and insert x and y coordinates into columns in attribute table. You'll find it under Geometry section of Field Calculator.[image].

Comment: GREAT! thanks! oneother thing, when getting X and Y and then saving, the values turn to "NULL" do you know why?

Comment: I got it now, just had to increase the precision and length of the figures. Thanks again!